# TSQL - Run date comparison for "duplicates"/false positives on initial query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, subquery

I'm pretty new to SQL and am working on pulling some data from several very large tables for analysis.  The data is basically triggered events for assets on a system.  The events all have a created_date (datetime) field that I care about.

I was able to put together the query below to get the data I need (YAY):

```
SELECT 
         event.efkey
        ,event.e_id
        ,event.e_key
        ,l.l_name
        ,event.created_date
        ,asset.a_id
        ,asset.asset_name
  FROM event
  LEFT JOIN asset
         ON event.a_key = asset.a_key
  LEFT JOIN l
         ON event.l_key = l.l_key


  WHERE event.e_key IN (350, 352, 378)

  ORDER BY asset.a_id, event.created_date
```

However, while this gives me the data for the specific events I want, I still have another problem. Assets can trigger these events repeatedly, which can result in large numbers of "false positives" for what I'm looking at.

What I need to do is go through the result set of the query above and remove any events for an asset that occur closer than N minutes together (say 30 minutes for this example). So IF the asset_ID is the same AND the event.created_date is within 30 minutes of another event for that asset in the set THEN I want that removed.  For example:

For the following records

```
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-01 12:30:30
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-01 12:35:31
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-01 12:40:33
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-01 12:45:42
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-02 12:30:30
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-02 13:00:30
a_id 1115 created 2016-02-01-12:30:30
```

I'd want to return only:

```
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-01 12:30:30 
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-02 12:30:30 
a_id 1124 created 2016-02-02 13:00:30 
a_id 1115 created 2016-02-01-12:30:30
```

I tried referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993008/select-non-duplicate-values-from-rows-that-are-less-than-a-specified-number-of-m) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160758/tsql-query-to-return-all-rows-that-are-within-5-mins-of-each-other) but I can't make the concepts there work for me.  I know I probably need to do a SELECT * FROM (my existing query) but I can't seem to do that without ending up with tons of "multi-part identifier can't be bound" errors (and I have no experience creating temp tables, my attempts at that have failed thus far). I also am not exactly sure how to use DATEDIFF as the date filtering function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you could dumb it down for a novice (or link to explanations) that would also be helpful!

Comment: So what do you want to do if you have 3 events that are about 20 minutes apart?  IE; you have an event at 1:30, 1:50 and 2:10.  Each are within the 30 minute window of the previous event, but the last 2 are separated by 40 minutes.  Do you want to show just the 1:30 or both the 1:30 and the 2:10 or something else entirely?

Comment: Oooh, yeah, good point. Ideally I'd want to show the 1:30, drop the 1:50, and show the 2:10!

Comment: This might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87d2b1d5-ee1e-4906-a499-3e38775614d3/tsql-group-by-n-minutes?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trickier problem than it initially appears.  The hard part is capturing the previous good row and removing the next bad rows but not allowing those bad rows to influence whether or not the next row is good.  Here is what I came up with.  I've tried to explain what is going on with comments in the code.

```
--sample data since I don't have your table structure and your original query won't work for me
declare @events table
(
  id int,
  timestamp datetime
)

--note that I changed some of your sample data to test some different scenarios
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:30:30')
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:35:31')
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:40:33')
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-01 13:05:42')
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-02 12:30:30')
insert into @events values( 1124, '2016-02-02 13:00:30')
insert into @events values( 1115, '2016-02-01 12:30:30')

--using a cte here to split the result set of your query into groups
--by id (you would want to partition by whatever criteria you use
--to determine that rows are talking about the same event)
--the row_number function gets the row number for each row within that 
--id partition
--the over clause specifies how to break up the result set into groups 
--(partitions) and what order to put the rows in within that group so 
--that the numbering stays consistant
;with orderedEvents as
(
    select id, timestamp, row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) as rn
    from @events
    --you would replace @events here with your query
)
--using a second recursive cte here to determine which rows are "good"
--and which ones are not.  
, previousGoodTimestamps as 
(
    --this is the "seeding" part of the recursive cte where I pick the
    --first rows of each group as being a desired result.  Since they 
    --are the first in each group, I know they are good.  I also assign
    --their timestamp as the previous good timestamp since I know that 
    --this row is good.
    select id, timestamp, rn, timestamp as prev_good_timestamp, 1 as is_good
    from orderedEvents
    where rn = 1

    union all

    --this is the recursive part of the cte.  It takes the rows we have
    --already added to this result set and joins those to the "next" rows
    --(as defined by our ordering in the first cte).  Then we output
    --those rows and do some calculations to determine if this row is 
    --"good" or not.  If it is "good" we set it's timestamp as the
    --previous good row timestamp so that rows that come after this one 
    --can use it to determine if they are good or not.  If a row is "bad"
    --we just forward along the last known good timestamp to the next row.
    --
    --We also determine if a row is good by checking if the last good row
    --timestamp plus 30 minutes is less than or equal to the current row's
    --timestamp.  If it is then the row is good.
    select e2.id
        , e2.timestamp
        , e2.rn
        , last_good_timestamp.timestamp
        , case
            when dateadd(mi, 30, last_good_timestamp.timestamp) <= e2.timestamp then 1
            else 0
          end
    from previousGoodTimestamps e1
    inner join orderedEvents e2 on e2.id = e1.id and e2.rn = e1.rn + 1
    --I used a cross apply here to calculate the last good row timestamp
    --once.  I could have used two identical subqueries above in the select
    --and case statements, but I would rather not duplicate the code.
    cross apply
    (
        select case 
                 when e1.is_good = 1 then e1.timestamp --if the last row is good, just use it's timestamp
                 else e1.prev_good_timestamp --the last row was bad, forward on what it had for the last good timestamp
               end as timestamp
    ) last_good_timestamp
)
select *
from previousGoodTimestamps
where is_good = 1 --only take the "good" rows
```

Links to MSDN for some of the more complicated things here:

- [CTEs and Recursive CTEs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, this is incredible! THANK YOU! I get exactly the result set I need!  And thank you so much for the detailed comments and links. This is definitely above my level now, but I'll definitely be studying up. I've never heard of CTEs before, so I'll be trying some tutorials later this week. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Id Int Identity, A_Id Int, CreatedDate DateTime );
insert into @Samples ( A_Id, CreatedDate ) values
  ( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:30:30' ),
  ( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:35:31' ),
  ( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:40:33' ),
  ( 1124, '2016-02-01 12:45:42' ),
  ( 1124, '2016-02-02 12:30:30' ),
  ( 1124, '2016-02-02 13:00:30' ),
  ( 1125, '2016-02-01 12:30:30' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Calculate the windows of 30 minutes before and after each   CreatedDate   and check for conflicts with other rows.
with Ranges as (
  select Id, A_Id, CreatedDate,
    DateAdd( minute, -30, S.CreatedDate ) as RangeStart, DateAdd( minute, 30, S.CreatedDate ) as RangeEnd
    from @Samples as S )
  select Id, A_Id, CreatedDate, RangeStart, RangeEnd,
    -- Check for a conflict with another row with:
    --   the same   A_Id   value and an earlier   CreatedDate   that falls inside the +/-30 minute range.
    case when exists ( select 42 from @Samples where A_Id = R.A_Id and CreatedDate < R.CreatedDate and R.RangeStart < CreatedDate and CreatedDate < R.RangeEnd ) then 1
      else 0 end as Conflict
    from Ranges as R;
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case when there are 3 events about 20 minutes apart (ie. 1:30, 1:50 and 2:10).  This would mark the 2:10 as a conflict when the comments on the question show it should not be.

Comment: @Becuzz You're right, I was coding as the requirements were being clarified. ;-) I do like your technique of forwarding the last good date/time through the CTE in order to work around the limitations of CTEs.